# Using VPN over TCP 80, 443 and UDP 53,2049?

Tags: vpn

My VPN client allows me to use the VPN service on TCP 443 , 80 ports and UDP 53,2049 ports. Connecting to which of the above ports will help in giving max security?

Comment: The port used is irrelevant for security, the protocol used on this port is relevant instead. If the used protocol differs between the ports please provide the details which protocol is used by editing your question. If the same protocol is used on all ports than it provides the same security on all ports.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am using OpenVPN.

Comment: Using Port TCP/443 might be the least suspicious.

Comment: @Lukas I was using TCP 443 but the connection sometimes goes in unstable mode. But while using TCP 80 its always stable.

Comment: @Skynet: OpenVPN can use any port on TCP or UDP. Thus these are just different ports offered by your VPN provider to pass through firewalls, but they don't differ in the security of the connection they offer. They might differ in how easy it is to pass filters or analysis but this depends more on the environment where you use the VPN, i.e. which restrictions and analysis is employed there.

Answer (score 2):

Like the others say, the port won't give any additional security.  The only advantage would be that you manage to "connect through" an egress filtering firewall.

For example, if you connect on port 53/udp, a company will see a large number of (malformed) packets on "DNS", so that may cause a red flag.  A network may also only allow only the use of their local DNS servers (which forward and cache DNS traffic).

Your "best bet" may be 443/tcp, since many networks *may* just allow this encrypted, binary, traffic.  Having said that, proper "deep packet" inspection would see that you don't have a proper TLS connection setup; and flag this as malicious and throttle it / shut it down.

Answer (score 1):

The port you choose doesn't affect the security of the VPN. Using different ports only helps to avoid/bypass firewall rules

Of course if network administrators inspect your traffic they'll detect that you're using a different protocol than the usual for that specific port (f.e. HTTP for port 80). In this case the administrators won't see what you're doing with the VPN but they'll know that you're using one. For this situation you may want to prefer port 443 as it usually handles encrypted that may be unnoticed

Answer (score 0):

Port number did not add any value for the security of your VPN .
Normally the VPN providers provide their VPN service over different ports to allow their customers to pass the firewall rules.cause In most cases the mentioned ports http,https,DNS will be open to the internet.
But in case your connection will pass through Next Generation firewall, The firewall can detect if the flow is real protocol flow or it is something else and it can be blocked.